# MSBuild: Unable to find the path

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-task, msbuildcommunitytasks, msbuildextensionpack

I am using following script within my build file. I have installed MSBuildExtensionPack on the build server.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003"
         ToolsVersion="4.0"
         DefaultTargets="StopIT">

 <Import Project=".\thirdparty\tools\MsBuildExtensions"/>

<Target Name="StopIT">
        <MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Computer.WindowsService TaskAction="Stop" ServiceName="AppServices"  MachineName="MyMachineName"/>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

After running the script, I am getting following error:

The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\ExtensionPack\4.0\MSBuild.ExtensionPack.tasks" was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

If i look into the machine, I can find this file under: "C:\Program Files\MSBuild\ExtensionPack\4.0\MSBuild.ExtensionPack.tasks" location.

**How can I inform the build script to look into correct path.**

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, I installed the 32 bit version which by default get installed at C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\ExtensionPack\4.0 location. I am not sure if there is an explicit way to specify another path.

Thank you